# Why cant my EMR cluster see my S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

I need my EMR cluster to see a private S3 bucket. The bucket is only visible via a role we will call x-role. I updated my IAM trust relationship of the x-role to allow the assume-role function to the default EMR role. And yes, x-role has the proper S3 permissions to see all s3 resources.

X-role's trust relationship looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::current_account_number:role/team-dev-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::current_account_number:role/app-admin-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::current_account_number:role/EMR_DefaultRole",
                    "arn:aws:iam::current_account_number:role/EMR_EC2_DefaultRole"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I added both the EMR_DefaultRole and EMR_EC2_DefaultRole to this to try to troubleshoot, but I believe EMR_EC2_DefaultRole is the default instance profile of EMR, and out of the 2 arns this is the only one that needs proper access.

Here is a screenshot of my default EMR security configuration:
[image]

Why cant my EMR cluster see the S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The EMR role has assume role permissions but not direct access to S3.

In order to access S3, use assume role API to get temporary credentials for the role which has S3 permissions

Example code to fetch temp creds

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

assumed_role_response = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::account-of-role-to-assume:role/name-of-role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession12345"
)

credentials = assumed_role_response['Credentials']

access_key = credentials['AccessKeyId'],
secret_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
token = credentials['SessionToken'],

boto3_session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, 
    aws_session_token=token
)

s3_client = boto3_session.client('s3')
```

Use this **s3_client** for your s3 operations

Comment: Could you please clarify what this python code has to do with EMR, and how it should be used in EMR?

Comment: I just gave you a example code for assume role, all you need to do it assume the role (x-role in your case), get temp creds and access the bucket, you can use any language